# Why can't I use the word 'to' after the verb 'helped'?

Tags: grammar, infinitives, bare-infinitive

I know it is incorrect to say, "They helped to her" and that it should be, "They helped her", but why is the word "to" not needed? And yet the word *to* is in this sentence: "They helped **to** get her free." Why is that?

Comment: In German, "her" would be in the Dative (indirect object) case, which is often indicated in English by _to_, This is true only of the German verb _helfen_, afaik, though there may be other such verbs.

Comment: Either of these is fine: "They helped get her free" versus "They helped her get free".  However, they mean different things.

Answer (score 2):

Because *help* (like *want* and *force*) takes a direct object for the person or actor and optionally an infinitive clause with *to*.

[That is a more detailed version of *because it does*, some form of which is the whole of the answer to almost all questions about *why* languages are the way they are].

Answer (score 0):

*help* takes the direct object without any preposition.

*help* is used with the preposition *to* then it is followed with the verb.

Here is the sentence with the direct object and the verb:

> He **helped her to feel** the pleasure.